# domain.events appears to be a DNS hostname but cannot match TLD against known list

Tags: orders, error, email

When entering an order manually we see this error (and cannot complete the order)

```
"Email" is not a valid hostname.
'domain.events' appears to be a DNS hostname but cannot match TLD against known list
'domain.events' appears to be a local network name but local network names are not allowed
```

**Question:** Has anyone encountered this before? (and fixed) .. might need to report this one with more and more TLD's coming

thanks, Sean

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this error comes from the class `Zend_Validate_EmailAddress`. In this class you will see the function `_validateHostnamePart` that validates the hostname part of an email address. From what I know zend works it way down to `Zend_Validate_Hostname::isValid` and in here the email hostname is validated against an array of valid top level domains.

```
protected $_validTlds
```

In your case this array will not contain `events`. Now Zend mention that they validate domains from a list at http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db/ which does contain `events` as a valid options. So I guess this is an issue with the version of Zend in Magento being outdated.

You should be able to extend this and update the array to contain all the new values.